# after 14.10 upgrade x session locks after resume or vt switch

Tags: xorg, suspend, 14.10, freeze

Since upgrading from Ubuntu desktop to 14.04 to 14.10, I am having an
issue with with my X session becoming unresponsive when resuming from
suspend or switching virtual terminals.  It occurs with about one time
in every four when either of these events occur.  (Needless to say it
is very frustrating.)  Once it happens, the X display does not update,
except for motion of the mouse cursor, nor does it respond to click or
keyboard events.  Switching terminals or performing a suspend/resume
cycle will not recover a session once in this state.  Only through
restarting X (lightdm service) am I able to resume using X.

Users with similar issues have been asked to provide logs from Xorg,
syslog, and dmesg.  The below links point to copies of these logs captured
immediately after an incident.  I am unable to interpret them myself.

Please advise how I can resolve or at least make progress debugging
the problem.

[Xorg.0.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9435980/)

[syslog](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9435997/)

[dmesg](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9435998/)